# How to multiply lines into ranges with linux regex commands

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl, csv

I have a csv file containing lines such as the below:

```
"AAAAA","ABC","355 69 2000405 / 2000407"
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 000 / 005"
```

I want to have an output like the below:

```
"AAAAA","ABC","355 69 2000405"
"AAAAA","ABC","355 69 2000406"
"AAAAA","ABC","355 69 2000407"
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 000"
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 001"
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 002"
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 003" 
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 004"
"BBBBB","ABC","1 87630444120 005"
```

as the above explains, I want the number before the slash to be the starting point of the range and the number after the slash to be the end of the range. also, I need the other column to be repeated.

I tried this using Perl, it showed some results, but not the result I needed.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @anubhava that is how the file is generated, there is no specific reason behind it

Comment: @serenesat this is what i tried - perl -lne 'if (m{(.*) (.*) (.*)/(.*)}) {print $1, for $3 .. $4}'

Comment: @luuke what do you need is: duplicate the content before the / from 0 to the value after / ? that's means in the first case from 0 to 2000407 ? is it right?

Comment: @ClaudioM I don't think it should be from 0 to 2000407, but rather from 2000405 to 2000407. I think he is duplicating each line with the minimum for the range of duplication being the number appearing before the `/`, and maximum being the number after the `/`. So from `2000405 - 2000407` and `000 - 005`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  # Parse the input into three useful bits
  my ($data, $start, $end) = m|(.* )(\d+) / (\d+)|;

  # Use $start and $end to control repetition
  for my $x ($start .. $end) {
    print qq[$data$x"\n];
  }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$ ./this_program your_input_file > some_output_file
```

Comment: I think your script creates an extra space before the last digit. Perhaps if you change `print qq[$data $x"\n];` to `print qq[$data$x"\n];`, it will get rid of the extra space.

Comment: @DaveCross can you explain what is $x ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. `$x` is a scalar variable. It's the loop variable for the `for` loop. Each time around the `for` loop, `$x` is given the next value from the range `$start .. $end`.

Answer (score 0):

This one works as long as the input format of the data does not change heavy.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  number_before_slash="$(echo ${line%%/*} | awk '{print $NF}')"
  number_after_slash="$(echo ${line##*/} | egrep -o '[0-9]*')"
  rest_of_line="$(echo ${line%%/*} | awk '{for (j=1; j<=NF-1; ++j) print $j}')"

  format="printf '${rest_of_line} %0${#number_before_slash}d\n' {$(echo ${number_before_slash})..$(echo ${number_after_slash})}"
  eval ${format}
  echo ""
done < <(cat myfile.csv | awk -F"#" '{print $1}' | egrep -v  '^[[:space:]]*$')
```

Your data stays in myfile.csv of course. Additionally it removes comments and blank lines from the input file.